# Play Framework: How do I get querystring value inside html template file

Tags: java, html, scala, playframework-2.0

I am working on Play Framework 2.0 for Java and I have a querystring url like `http://localhost:9000/project/detail?id=1`, when this url hits It will call a HTML template file eg.`detail.scala.html`. So I want to check is there querystring exist in url in my HTML file.

ex:

```
@if(existsQueryString) 
         @showPerticularProductDetail
else
         @showAllProductList
```

Please help me or give any suggestion for this. I dont want to pass some variable or any flag from controller to view for checking the condition. I just want to check is querystring there in url inside my HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the request either directly if you're in a Java project, or via an implicit parameter if you are in a Scala project.

In a Java project, you can use it directly to check the queryString :

```
@if(request.queryString.containsKey("myKey")){
     @showPerticularProductDetail
else
     @showAllProductList
```

If you're in a Scala project, you need to add the request as an implicit parameter of your view :

```
@(title: String)(implicit request: play.api.mvc.Request)
```

And your controller should also declare this implicit parameter :

```
def detail = Action { implicit request =>
    ...
    myTemplate.render()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do you know this? I couldn't get a document for this?

Comment: You're right that it's not documented. I know this by going through the source code of the framework.